# Issues When Repositionin TableCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I recently came across a interesting [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture) on Ray Wenderlich's site on how to reposition TableCells by using a long hold gesture and dragging them, to change the order. It all works fine but I believe it's interfering with my core data fetching, because I reposition the cell then click on it which pushes me to another view and when I go back the cells go back into the order they were in before I moved them -_- I can't pint point the line that's causing this problem. So if you have any suggestions please feel free to let me know! Thanks!

TableView.m:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the lists from persistent data store
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"List"];
    self.lists = [[[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.lists.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *list = [self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[list valueForKey:@"name"]];

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add List" message:@"Create a New Wish List" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [alert setTag:2];
    [alert show];
    alert.delegate = self;
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != 0 && alertView.tag == 2) {
        UITextField *tf = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        // Create a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newList = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newList setValue:tf.text forKey:@"name"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"List"];
    self.lists = [[[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }
        // Remove list from table view
        [self.lists removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Storyboard support

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    WishListView *wishListController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
    List *selectedList = self.lists[indexPath.row];
    wishListController.list = selectedList;
    wishListController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureRecognized:)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}
- (IBAction)longPressGestureRecognized:(id)sender {

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = longPress.state;

    CGPoint location = [longPress locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    static UIView       *snapshot = nil;        ///< A snapshot of the row user is moving.
    static NSIndexPath  *sourceIndexPath = nil; ///< Initial index path, where gesture begins.

    switch (state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            if (indexPath) {
                sourceIndexPath = indexPath;

                UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                // Take a snapshot of the selected row using helper method.
                snapshot = [self customSnapshotFromView:cell];

                // Add the snapshot as subview, centered at cell's center...
                __block CGPoint center = cell.center;
                snapshot.center = center;
                snapshot.alpha = 0.0;
                [self.tableView addSubview:snapshot];
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

                    // Offset for gesture location.
                    center.y = location.y;
                    snapshot.center = center;
                    snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
                    snapshot.alpha = 0.98;

                    // Black out.
                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                } completion:nil];
            }
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            CGPoint center = snapshot.center;
            center.y = location.y;
            snapshot.center = center;

            // Is destination valid and is it different from source?
            if (indexPath && ![indexPath isEqual:sourceIndexPath]) {

                // ... update data source.
               [self.lists exchangeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

                // ... move the rows.
                [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:indexPath];

                // ... and update source so it is in sync with UI changes.
                sourceIndexPath = indexPath;
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            // Clean up.
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

                snapshot.center = cell.center;
                snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                snapshot.alpha = 0.0;

                // Undo the black-out effect we did.
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                [snapshot removeFromSuperview];
                snapshot = nil;

            }];
            sourceIndexPath = nil;
            break;
        }
    }
}
- (UIView *)customSnapshotFromView:(UIView *)inputView {

    UIView *snapshot = [inputView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
    snapshot.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    snapshot.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
    snapshot.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
    snapshot.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    snapshot.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
    return snapshot;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are executing a new fetch request and repopulating `self.lists` every time the view appears in `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`. When you reorder the cells you are changing the order in that local array but not in the actual core data store, so the new fetched data is always in the same order.

A quick fix for this would be to move your fetchrequest into somewhere that only gets executed once like `viewDidLoad`.

Of course if you need this ordering to persist even outside of this view (on app relaunches, in other places), you'll need to actually save either the whole array or at least the object ordering somehow.